# Xamarin FreshMvvm Simple Binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding, freshmvvm

I have a simple question. How do I access an entry value from a .xaml file in the pagemodel with the FreshMvvm framework.I want the default value that's set in the settings.cs constructor to be what the user inputs in the entry field.

Thanks!

testpage.xaml:

```
<Label Text="Set Server Address (FreshMvvm Binding):" />
<Entry Text="{Binding Settings.SyncServiceAddress}" Placeholder="Server IP Address" />       
<Button Text="Sync Web Service - (FreshMvvm Binding)" Command="{Binding SyncButtonFreshMvvmBinding_Clicked}" />
```

testpagemodel.cs:

```
public override void Init(object initData)
{
    if (initData != null)
    {
        Settings = (Settings)initData;
    }
    else
    {
        Settings = new Settings(); 
    }
}

public Command SyncButtonFreshMvvmBinding_Clicked
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            string serverAddress = Settings.SyncServiceAddress;
            SyncService.PullNewXMLData(serverAddress);
            await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<DashboardPageModel>();
        });
    }
}
```

settings.cs:

```
public class Settings : ObservableObject
{
    // Constructor
    public Settings()
    {
        // Default value
        SyncServiceAddress = "http://localhost/psm/service.aspx";
    }

    // Properties
    public string SyncServiceAddress { get; set; }
    public string UserIDSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi useruseruser: How is your Settings property defined in testpagemodel.cs, is it public? 
And can you bind any simple string property to the Entry text box to check your pages BindingContext is all wired up in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that the UI only needs to know about a limited set of properties, its ok to create a bindable property in the ViewModel so you're not trying to bind to a nested property.

Create a new string property in the ViewModel called SyncServiceAddress;

```
public string SyncServiceAddress
{
    get{
        return Settings.SyncServiceAddress;
    }
    set{
       Settings.SyncServiceAddress = value;
    }
}
```

Then update your XAML to this.

```
<Entry Text="{Binding SyncServiceAddress}" Placeholder="Server IP Address" />
```

This should resolve your issue.